# C++ enum is not a member of

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to access a enum that is defined in a class of a library (ogdf) I use.

[See line 65 here](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/_stress_minimization_8h_source.html) for the definition of the enum in the library.

If I try to access it like that (which I would think is the correct way):

```
ogdf::StressMinimization::TERMINATION_CRITERION::POSITION_DIFFERENCE
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘ogdf::StressMinimization::TERMINATION_CRITERION’ has not been declared
```

If I try to do it like that:

```
ogdf::StressMinimization::POSITION_DIFFERENCE
```

I get this error:

```
error: ‘POSITION_DIFFERENCE’ is not a member of ‘ogdf::StressMinimization’
```

Of course I'm including the header in my .cpp file via:

```
#include <ogdf/energybased/StressMinimization.h>
```

As this is part of the ogdf library, there are no problems with circular includes, which seems to be most frequent problem that causes that.

I can't see why this is happening, any help is greatly appreciated!
If you need any further details, please let me know, I'll update the question.

Comment: `ogdf::StressMinimization::POSITION_DIFFERENCE` looks okay. Can you access other members?

Comment: is this the only one error? could be a result of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on the latest, it may be that the name of the enum changed and that documentation is old; looks like that documentation is from 2015, latest snapshots are (currently) from February 2017.  From https://github.com/ogdf/ogdf/blob/master/include/ogdf/energybased/StressMinimization.h, the enum looks like this now:

```
enum class TerminationCriterion {
    None, PositionDifference, Stress
};
```

So, try replacing `TERMINATION_CRITERION` with TerminationCriterion and/or `POSITION_DIFFERENCE` with `PositionDifference` and see if that works.

Comment: I feel stupid. I should have looked into it myself, never trust a documentation.